# Playframework [1.2.7] dependencies failing

Tags: playframework, dependencies, ivy, dependency-management, playframework-1.x

We're experiencing a problem with play frameworks dependency management which was working fine a couple of days ago. We haven't made any configuration changes or changes to the dependency file but are getting the following errors on both our build server and locally (both located on different networks and ISP's).

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: vsvr1#minifymod;1.0.9

==== vsvr1: tried

  -- artifact vsvr1#minifymod;1.0.9!minifymod.jar:

  https://github.com/maklemenz/minifymod/raw/master/dist/minifymod-1.0.9.zip

    [NOT FOUND  ] play#recaptcha;1.3!recaptcha.zip(jar) (139ms)

==== playContributedModules: tried

  http://www.playframework.org/modules/recaptcha-1.3.zip

    [FAILED     ] play#excel;1.2.3!excel.zip(jar): Connection refused (520ms)

    [FAILED     ] play#excel;1.2.3!excel.zip(jar): Connection refused (520ms)

==== playContributedModules: tried

  http://www.playframework.org/modules/excel-1.2.3.zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: vsvr1#minifymod;1.0.9: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: play#recaptcha;1.3!recaptcha.zip(jar)

    :: play#excel;1.2.3!excel.zip(jar)

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name url=https://github.com/maklemenz/minifymod/raw/master/dist/minifymod-1.0.9.zip

Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://www.playframework.org/modules/recaptcha-1.3.zip
```

I cant seem to find a solution to this and so far its preventing us doing any new builds as the dependencies are missing. The failed files seems to change each time too and when manually trying to download them in a browser we can without a problem.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: Having the same issue :(
Did you ever come up with the solution?

Comment: So it turned out the problem was with Github, they have changed the URL structure for downloading files which was causing a redirect that Ivy couldn't handle. I have since stopped referencing it from github and used a git submodule but am having another problem now with Play always treating the module folder as a zip even though its a project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540542/playframework-1-2-7-dependencies-failing) you can use jvm option `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` as workaround.

Comment: @fraserh did you specify that jsse option in the dependency command call like this `play deps . --sync -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` ? That didn't work for me for a module stored at https://github.com/tazmaniax/play-markdown/releases/download/1.9/play-markdown-1.9.zip. Just keep getting a 403 in the output log

Comment: Sergey, the link you added is recurssive :(