# Playframework 1.4.1: Play dependencies don't download

Tags: java, playframework

I can't download dependencies from play module centre. I've got the following error message for all libraries:

> ~
>
> ~ Oops,
>
> ~ Cannot fetch the modules list from https://www.playframework.com/modules …

I try do this from cmd like the following; however I get an error message:

```
play install pdf-0.9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540542/playframework-1-2-7-dependencies-failing

Comment: Having the same problem!! Comment above is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem with play1 modules, but they are now restored, and everything should be working as expected. See https://twitter.com/playframework/status/976878195596292097

It was the result of a problem with our AWS instance at the start last Monday (April 19).